# Shorten MQTT topic filtering function

Tags: scala, logic, mqtt, matching

I wrote the following logic function, but I am sure it is possible to write it (way) shorter.
In case you are unfamiliar with MQTT wildcards, [you can read up on them here.](https://www.hivemq.com/blog/mqtt-essentials-part-5-mqtt-topics-best-practices/)

`self` is the topic we are "subscribed" to, containing zero or more wildcards. `incoming` is the topic we received something on, which must match the `self` topic either fully, or conforming to the wildcard rules.

All my tests on this function succeed, but I just don't like the lengthiness and "iffyness" of this Scala function.

```scala
def filterTopic(incoming: String, self: String): Boolean = {
  if (incoming == self || self == "#") {
    true
  } else if (self.startsWith("#") || (self.contains("#") && !self.endsWith("#")) || self.endsWith("+")) {
    false
  } else {
    var valid = true
    val selfSplit = self.split('/')
    var j = 0

    for (i <- selfSplit.indices) {
      if (selfSplit(i) != "+" && selfSplit(i) != "#" && selfSplit(i) != incoming.split('/')(i)) {
        valid = false
      }
      j += 1
    }

    if (j < selfSplit.length && selfSplit(j) == "#") {
      j += 1
    }

    j == selfSplit.length && valid
  }
}
```

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because nothing is actually not working here, it would probably fit better on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: is there a reason that a topic can't end with `+`?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a shot at it assuming that '+' can be at the end and that the topics are otherwise well-structured

```scala
    def filterTopic(incoming: String, self: String): Boolean = {
        // helper function that works on lists of parts of the topics
        def go(incParts: List[String], sParts: List[String]): Boolean = (incParts, sParts) match {
            // if they're equivalent lists, the topics match
            case (is, ss) if is == ss => true
            // if sParts is just a single "#", the topics match
            case (_, "#" :: Nil) => true
            // if sParts starts with '+', just check if the rest match
            case (_ :: is, s :: ss) if s == "+" =>
                go(is, ss)
            // otherwise the first parts have to match, and we check the rest
            case (i :: is, s :: ss) if i == s =>
                go(is, ss)
            // otherwise they don't match
            case _ => false
        }

        // split the topic strings into parts 
        go(incoming.split('/').toList, self.split('/').toList)
    }
```